# How to move files from one folder to another?

Tags: scala

I need to move files for one folder to another

To do this in java I would create a method something like :

```
private boolean moveFile(List<String> names, dir moveTo){

  for(String file : names){
    //copy the file from one dir to another
  }

}
```

Is there a more 'functional' way to do this in scala or a better way? Maybe using scala I do not even need to loop over the files ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're doing nothing but a side effect so it's not a very functional task per se. Maybe it's a bit shorter with the foreach function, but there's not much of a difference.